# What is the convention for switching vhosts to new_feature branch in git?

Tags: git, web-applications, git-branch

When using git for version control, I understand it is convention to create a new branch for each new feature.

I develop web applications in php on an apache server, and I don't know how to painlessly handle this development mode.

And here is my question: Is switching the vhost to the current git branch folder you're working on the common practice?

**FURTHER EXPLANATION**

Scenario:
Git repo is in /var/www/
I have a master branch which is recognized in the browser through vhost as master.localhost and a develop branch that is recognized as develop.localhost in the browser. I'm browsing around develop.localhost and recognize a new feature that needs to be developed. I branch the repository to /add-server-side-validation/. To begin testing/viewing this in the browser, I need to add a new vhost like add-server-side-validation.localhost. What is the elegant/conventional way to do this?

Comment: Still a bit opaque.  Are you adding a new virtual host on your web server in order to add a new feature (very strange), or adding a new feature to an existing virtual host (very common). If the latter, will that feature be rolled out to other virtual hosts and how do those other virtual hosts relate to the git repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) to establish your branching convention.

Comment: Yes thank you--I already am going to use this branching model. My question however is more about how to use that branching model for actual web development and testing.

Answer (score 0):

While many people recommend using feature branches, it is hardly the only method in common use.  You should be aware that it exists but don't feel bound to it if there are good reasons why something else might be better.

I don't fully follow the vhost/current git branch folder question.  There are several ways of using git with web sites.  You could have a git repo per vhost, you could have different subdirectories of a git repo being different vhosts, and yes you could have different branches be different vhosts.

I would say the latter is fairly rare.  Only if there is great similarity to the vhosts where you might want to merge back and forth between the vhosts (or from some master "template" branch to each vhost in turn) might different branches make sense.  Of course, you could also do the same template thing with multiple repositories where template was a remote people could pull and merge from.  Using a meta-repository system like gitslave (or to a lesser extent in this case, git-submodules) might help automation of getting everyone merged from a common source.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I have updated the question to explain my scenario.